# Move a Vertex to an existing cluster in OrientDB using Gremlin

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, orientdb2.2

I am new to OrientDB, using OrientDB 2.2.20. How do I move a vertex in an existing cluster using Gremlin

Following move vertex command is in SQL

`MOVE VERTEX (select * from SClosure where (eType="DSLAM")) TO CLUSTER:myCluster`

The inner query gets the @rid to be moved to an existing cluster "myCluster"

Is there a Gremlin version of this query? It is needed for my requirement

Comment: No sorry, this is out of the scope of Gremlin specs AFAIK. Actually, OrientDB was the first Graph Database to have introduced the refactoring of a graph, I don't know now if other Graph Databases copied this feature.